# .NET IPAddress Class is converting IPv6 to Mapped IP Address

Tags: .net

I have IPv6 string and I want to make the IPAddress object. I tried the following code

```
String ipString = "2400:3C00:3FFE:0000:0000:5EFE:8999:48AA";
System.Net.IPAddress address;
IPAddress.TryParse(ipString, out address);
```

but address.ToString() is returning the value  "2400:3c00:3ffe::5efe:137.153.72.170".

Why this has been converted to mix ip?

Answer (score 1):

This is, AFAIK, happening on Windows 2003 + XP (maybe Vista, but I'm not sure), because of their implementation of IPv6. On newer OSes it will be ok.

Comment: I got this on Windows 7 and also on windows server 2008 R2.

Comment: I've been trying this on Windows 7 with VS2012. Some IPv6 addresses work fine (::1, my local IP). Others show what you're seeing. Don't know why.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. If I changed two consecutive zeroes it works like for   "2400:3C00:3FFE:1000:1000:5EFE:8999:48AA"

Comment: Check out this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863352/what-dictates-the-formatting-of-ipv6-addresses-by-system-net-ipaddress-tostring